# error while runnging manage.py

Tags: python, django

```
C:\Python27\mysastha>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: cannot import name execute_from_command_line
```

manage.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: what happens if you start a python shell and try the import there (ie check that this statement works) - from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

Comment: Don't put your source code in `C:\Python27`, this is not the directory for your applications.

Comment: I am running it from project directory

Comment: same error while I do from python shell.django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

Comment: check your django version, not properly installed ?

Comment: how do I check I tried running django-admin.py I still get the same error

Comment: when I use SQLite it works fine only with mongo I get this error

Comment: some how I have resolved the error..not sure how tried many things